# How to resolve "Authentication token expired" of Evernote

Tags: python, evernote

I'm developing a batch program which get note from Evernote API daily on Linux.
Please give me some advice about this situation.

Sep 2 2017: I got Consumer Key, Secret and Developer Token for Sandbox.
Sep 9 2017: I got Consumer Key, Secret and Developer Token for Production.
Sep 9-25: My program could access sandbox and production Evernote API.
Sep 26: only production Evernote API replied this exception:

```
  EDAMUserException(errorCode=9, parameter='authenticationToken')
```

I understood this message's meaning:

```
  AUTH_EXPIRED
  Authentication token expired
```

This is my Python source:

```
  config = {'token': dev_token, 'sandbox': flag,}
  client = EvernoteClient(**config)
  note_store = client.get_note_store() # exception raises here
```

I seem "need to reauthenticate and obtain a new authentication token" according to this page:
  https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/error_handling.php#common

So I'd like to get new developer token. But I can't do it on this page:
  https://www.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action
  "Update: the creation of developer tokens is temporarily disabled." desplayed.
  "Create a developer token" button is disabled.

What should I do to access production API again?

One more.
Can my program get token automatically with OAuth?
It's batch program(no GUI). So I have no callback URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you mean by "automatically" but you need to go through the OAuth flow to get the access token. And Evernote OAuth requires a valid callback URL. See http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php

If you have an issue with creating dev token, please go to https://www.evernote.com/SupportLogin.action and reach out to the support team. They can get you connected with a new developer token.

Comment: Thank you.1.regenerating developer token
I asked it to the support team.
And I got new developer token.

2.using OAuth
I checked OAuth flow by your advice.
It has typing mail address and password process via web page.
I'm planning to pass this process without human operations (it means automatically) by making my batch program send a few http requests to save time regenerating new developer token every year.
Is this not good idea so much?